# After Taking Picture cannot select Use Photo or Retake

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, ios7, photo

So I'm trying to update an app for iOS 7 and I'm running into issues with my custom overlay.  The overlay is an image that I'm framing the photo with (both live and using a full resolution version to frame the final result in the camera roll).  The problem is that now, under iOS 7, the overlay, while transparent at the bottom, provides access to the regular "take picture" button, but for some reason will not let me tap on the "Use Photo" or "Retake" buttons that come up after the picture is snapped.  Here's the code snippet calling the view controller:

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = NO;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.showsCameraControls = YES;

// Overlay Creation
UIView* overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:picker.view.frame];
    overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PBOverlayView.png"]];
    [overlayView.layer setOpaque:NO];
    overlayView.opaque = NO;

picker.cameraOverlayView = overlayView;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: picker.allowsEditing = YES;

Answer (score 12):

Another approach could be to observe the notifications when the ImagePicker changes state and remove (or disable) your overlay when you move into the "Use Photo" screen.

```
- (void) addPhotoObservers {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(removeCameraOverlay) name:@"_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem" object:nil ];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(addCameraOverlay) name:@"_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidRejectItem" object:nil ];
}

- (void) removePhotoObservers {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

-(void)addCameraOverlay {
    if (self.cameraPicker) {
        self.cameraPicker.cameraOverlayView = self.myCameraOverlayView;
    }
}

-(void)removeCameraOverlay {
    if (self.cameraPicker) {
        self.cameraPicker.cameraOverlayView = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: those observers are a huge help when capturing the "Retake" and "Use Preview" clicks..you would think Apple would provide callbacks for those..

Comment: Thanks . But when I retake photo overlay is not displayed , for solution I have just changed if content to  self.cameraPicker.cameraOverlayView.hidden=NO and self.cameraPicker.cameraOverlayView=YES in addCameraOverlay and removeCameraOverlay respectively .

Answer (score 8):

You could set `User Enteraction Enabled` to `NO` on Overlay View ;) works for me

Answer (score 5):

Your problem: When you initialised the overlayView, you've set the frame to be the same size as that of the picker. 
    `UIView* overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:picker.view.frame];`

Explanation: Before capturing an image, the camera buttons are in the foreground of the overlayView, so that there's no issue pressing them.
After capturing an image (on the "retake/use preview page"), the overlayView is the one to be in the foreground, thus blocking the access to the buttons.
I know this to be an issue on iOS7, and not sure about other versions.

Possible solutions: Since this is a native problem within Apple's UIImagePickerController, I can only think of two solutions: (1) If possible, configure the overlayView to have a shorter frame which doesn't cover the bottom of the picker; (2) If you need the overlay to cover these buttons, you still have the exhausting option of configuring `self.imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;` but then you'd have to customize ALL of the camera behaviour (you can find many examples for that on the web).

Comment: Or you could set User Enteraction Enabled to NO on Overlay View ;) works for me

Answer (score 0):

After taking a photo, or animation on your overlay is done, i made it work by removing the overlay from its superview.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:1
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{

                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [self.view removeFromSuperview];
                 }];
```